# Output from JNI

Tags: eclipse, console, java-native-interface

When running custom JNI modules that contains native `printf` code in Eclipse, the output of the native `printf` calls is never shown. When invoking the same setup from the shell (`cmd.exe`), the output is shown.

Can Eclipse's console be configured to also show the native `printf` output?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have unwritten data in the stdout buffer - try flushing the stdout after your `printf`by adding `fflush(stdout);` statements after the prints.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush